# Application Map in a .Net Core 2.x console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, .net-core-2.0

Is there are a solution to implement functionality in **console** .Net core  2.x similar to one like in .Net core 2.0 ASP.NET Core.
For example, ability to see all components in Application Map in Azure and track all method execution?

My console app consists of the Main method that uses Cosmos DB and other Azure components (EventHub, etc) and I wish I could see dependencies in Application map.

There are a number of example on how to employ Application Insights for .Net Core ASP.Net but only a few examples for .net core and mainly with a to-do list on how to use Application Insights as a logging channel.

I am using standard .net core dependency injection and configuration.

Comment: That's not ASP.NET Core functionality. That's Application Insights and yes, you can use Application Insights in console applications. Have you checked [Application Insights for .NET console applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-console)?

Comment: Let me try this guide.